# Forumla field value showing always true issue

Tags: formula-field

A checkbox field is created and if the record created date and today's date have more than 8 hours difference then store value as true in the formula field and if the hours difference between created date and today's date is less than 8 hours then show the formula checkbox field false

```
      if((NOW() - CreatedDate )/24 < 8,true, false)
```

This above formula is not working

Comment: you need difference between Now and Createddate should be less than 8 then true or else it should be false?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala yes, 8hours difference need to findout

Comment: See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5).  Date addition/subtraction uses days, so you should multiply by 24, not divide.

Answer (score 1):

`Now()` will give current Datetime and `CreatedDate` will give createddatetime.
If we subtract these two fields we will get difference in days. As you need the difference in hours I guess you need to multiply with 8 instead of Division .

```
 if((NOW() - CreatedDate )*24 < 8,true, false)
```

This returns if hours are less than 8 then it returns True or else it returns False

As mentioned by @DerekF, in this formula we don't need If() condition as well as we have only one value and that too a boolean value to assign.

```
(NOW() - CreatedDate )*24 < 8
```

In the formula if above condition satisfies it will return true and if not it returns False. We no need to mention any `If()` here

Comment: yes, though using the `IF()` is completely unnecessary here. `IF(<condition>, true, false)` is exactly the same as `<condition>`, just with more typing (making your formula bigger for no reason, and increasing the chance that you'll make a mistake).

Comment: @DerekF, Agreed on it and updating the answer